# ORA-03135 on Select Statement

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

This is a very recurring issue with some Oracle's Database users and I have read and tried different approaches withous success.

I am experiencing ORA-03135 error during a SELECT statement. It happens only on specific records of one table. The table has a field defined as varchar(4000) and I discovered that the error occurs when I try to read a record with a big string at the field I told before (about 2000 characters or more).

After some reading I tried to set SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME, SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT,
SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT and SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT without success.

I don't think it is a timeout problem because if I try the same query on a client like Sqlplus it works ad i get the result instantly.

There is no firewall on the network and no alerts/logs are generated on server side when the error occurs. There is also no profile limitation.

I am using an Oracle 11.2 database running on Oracle Linux and PHP OCI8 to retrieve the data.

Is there any other place I could look for?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen the Oracle Knowledgebase document, "Troubleshooting ORA-3135 Connection Lost Contact (Doc ID 787354.1)".  This typically would be a firewall issue, but your set-up does not correspond. Perhaps a service request is needed here.

Comment: Check your alert log for errors occurring at the same time as the connection dropping. Maybe session is terminated because data can't be read... Even storage issue can cause ORA-03135

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just solved it...

I was wrong. It seems the error occurs on strings with some kind of crap at the end of it, not only big ones. Removing the last character solves the problem.

I will do some further investigation and try to discover exactly what is going on.

Edit 1:

100% sure now, the error occurs when the last string is an escape character "\n". Pretty funny, huh?